# Usage of `e` and `E` argument types in `xparse`?

Tags: xparse

What are the argument types `e` and `E` described in `xparse` package used for? Can someone give me a simple example to show the usage of them?

Comment: Erh, it is explained in the xparse manual. You can find it on texdoc.net

Comment: also note that you don't need `xparse` in current latex releases, `\NewDocumentCommand` is a built in latex command not needing  `xparse`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you commonly use subscripts that can be either math or text. You may want to ease the input by choosing `!` to introduce textual subscripts.

To make the example more interesting, you can have different types of variables that accept these kinds of subscripts. We can have scalars, vectors or maps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\variable}{o m e{_!^}}{%
  % #1 = style, #2 = variable name,
  % #3 = math subscript, #4 = text subscript, #5 = superscript
  % typeset the variable according to the style
  \IfValueTF{#1}{#1{#2}}{#2}%
  % typeset the superscript
  \IfValueT{#5}{^{#5}}%
  % now fix the subscripts
  \IfValueTF{#3}{% there is a math subscript
    % typeset it; if there is a textual subscript, add it after a comma
    _{#3\IfValueT{#4}{,\mathrm{#4}}}%
  }{% no math subscript
    \IfValueT{#4}{_{\mathrm{#4}}}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\scalar}{}{\variable}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vect}{}{\variable[\mathbf]}
\NewDocumentCommand{\map}{}{\variable[\mathsf]}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\scalar{a}\ne\vect{v}\ne\map{T} \\
\scalar{a}_{x}+\scalar{a}_{x}^{2} \\
\scalar{a}!{eff}+\scalar{a}!{eff}^{2} \\
\scalar{a}_{x}!{eff}+\scalar{a}_{x}!{eff}^2 \\
\vect{v}_{x}+\vect{v}_{x}^{2} \\
\vect{v}!{eff}+\vect{v}!{eff}^{2} \\
\vect{v}_{x}!{eff}+\vect{v}_{x}!{eff}^2 \\
\map{T}_{x}+\map{T}_{x}^{2} \\
\map{T}!{eff}+\map{T}!{eff}^{2} \\
\map{T}_{x}!{eff}+\map{T}_{x}!{eff}^2 \\
\map{T}!{eff}_{x}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The last line shows that the output is normalized to have the textual part after the math subscript independently on the input order.

Now you realize that you want to move down the subscripts even if there is no superscript. The `E` type comes to the rescue. Just change the order of the embellishments and provide `{}` as the default value for `^`.

This has the drawback that the `\scriptspace` would be added even without any embellishment. I leave the fix as an exercise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\variable}{o m E{^_!}{{}}}{%
  % #1 = style, #2 = variable name,
  % #3 = math subscript, #4 = text subscript, #5 = superscript
  % typeset the variable according to the style
  \IfValueTF{#1}{#1{#2}}{#2}%
  % typeset the superscript
  ^{#3}%
  % now fix the subscripts
  \IfValueTF{#4}{% there is a math subscript
    % typeset it; if there is a textual subscript, add it after a comma
    _{#4\IfValueT{#5}{,\mathrm{#5}}}%
  }{% no math subscript
    \IfValueT{#5}{_{\mathrm{#5}}}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\scalar}{}{\variable}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vect}{}{\variable[\mathbf]}
\NewDocumentCommand{\map}{}{\variable[\mathsf]}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\scalar{a}\ne\vect{v}\ne\map{T} \\
\scalar{a}_{x}+\scalar{a}_{x}^{2} \\
\scalar{a}!{eff}+\scalar{a}!{eff}^{2} \\
\scalar{a}_{x}!{eff}+\scalar{a}_{x}!{eff}^2 \\
\vect{v}_{x}+\vect{v}_{x}^{2} \\
\vect{v}!{eff}+\vect{v}!{eff}^{2} \\
\vect{v}_{x}!{eff}+\vect{v}_{x}!{eff}^2 \\
\map{T}_{x}+\map{T}_{x}^{2} \\
\map{T}!{eff}+\map{T}!{eff}^{2} \\
\map{T}_{x}!{eff}+\map{T}_{x}!{eff}^2 \\
\map{T}!{eff}_{x}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty interesting example! Thank you!